# Class object from a textfile to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, split

I want to read class object from a text file and then put it on a list. I get:activities.append(Activites(i[0], time[0], time[1], i[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range.
I dont want to specify a range because I want to be able to add activites in the list, how do I solve this problem?

textfile:

```
Activity # Time # Location
Football # 8-9 # Pitch
Basketball # 9-10 # Gym
Lunch # 11-12 # Home
Reading # 13-14 # Library
```

My Code:

```
class Activites:
    def __init__(self, name,startTime, endTime, location):
        self.name = name
        self.startTime = int(startTime)
        self.endTime = int(endTime)
        self.location = location

def filee_():
    activities = []
    f = open('text.txt', 'r').readlines()
    for i in f:
        i=i.split('#')
        time = i[1].split("-")
        activities.append(Activites(i[0], time[0], time[1], i[1]))
    return activities
```

Comment: You need to skip the first line because it doesn't contain data and trying to split `Time` on `-` won't give you two items. You could just do `for i in f[1:]:` to start at the second line.

Comment: You might consider to use [yaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) and then let a professional package like [pyyaml](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml) do the parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint
class Activity:
    def __init__(self, name, start_time, end_time, location):
        self.name = name
        self.start = int(start_time)
        self.end = int(end_time)
        self.location = location

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Activity[{{name:{self.name}, start:{self.start}, end:{self.end}, location:{self.location}}}]'

def read_file(filename):
    activities = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        next(f) # skip header
        for line in f:
            activity, time, location = line.strip().split(' # ')
            start, end = time.split('-')
            activities.append(Activity(activity, start, end, location))
    return activities

activities = read_file('sample.txt')
pprint(activities)
```

output

```
[Activity[{name:Football, start:8, end:9, location:Pitch}],
 Activity[{name:Basketball, start:9, end:10, location:Gym}],
 Activity[{name:Lunch, start:11, end:12, location:Home}],
 Activity[{name:Reading, start:13, end:14, location:Library}]]
```

Some thoughts - if you can change the input format it could be better. Also, you can use `csv` module to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something as follows:

```
activities = list(load_data_from_file('text.txt'))
```

Where `load_data_from_file` function has the following logic: (Please note that since you're only holding data in `Activity` class, I would use instead a `namedtuple`)

```
from collections import namedtuple


def load_data_from_file(file_name):
    Activity = namedtuple('Activity', 'name start_time end_time location')
    with open(file_name) as file:
        content = get_content_of(file)
        for line in content:
            parsed_data = parse_activity_data(line)
            yield Activity(*parsed_data)


def get_content_of(file):
    return file.read().splitlines()[1:]


def parse_activity_data(line):
    name, time_range, location = line.split(' # ')
    start_time, end_time = map(int, time_range.split('-'))
    return name, start_time, end_time, location
```

And `activities` list will have the following content:

```
[Activity(name='Football', start_time=8, end_time=9, location='Pitch'),
 Activity(name='Basketball', start_time=9, end_time=10, location='Gym'),
 Activity(name='Lunch', start_time=11, end_time=12, location='Home'),
 Activity(name='Reading', start_time=13, end_time=14, location='Library')]
```